# Is there any concept of trivial/non-trivial member function?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

To be emphasized,here the **member function** does not include special member functions like ctor/dtor or copy/move ctors/assignments.

For example,does the standard ever specify such functions as trivial or not?

```
class A
{
   void foo() {/*nothing here*/} //is this trivial or not?
}
```

Is there any necessity to specify whether such **member function** is trivial or not?From my point of view,all the **member functions** are user-defined,so all of them are non-trivial,am I right?

Comment: _all the member function is user defined_ No.

Comment: There is a [`TrivialType`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/TrivialType) concept.

Comment: @Constructor Note that what I said about member function does not include special member functions like ctor/dtor or copy/move ctors/assignments.

Comment: @Lingxi This page is not detailed about the concept.

Comment: Where abouts did you see this term?

Comment: @bigxiao sorry, **trival** is only used to your "special member".

Comment: @Lingxi No, trivial type is used to describe class type, not a function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In C++ the term "trivial function" is only relevant to constructors, destructors, and assignment operators.  The term has no meaning with respect to regular member functions.

As you note, regular member functions are never implicit, and only implicit member functions can be trivial.  So if you insist on asking whether a regular member function is trivial, the answer is always "no."

Comment: Hello, could you tell me are there trivial destructor, too? I never heard of it.

Comment: @Constructor: Yes, implicit destructors can be trivial.  The rules are roughly similar to the rules for constructors (and given your name I'm sure you know what those rules are).